# Angular 2 - Directive to transform input before storing it in the model (e.g. show 1 but store 1000)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to write a directive that shows a value
other than the underlying ngModel.

For example: A user enters and sees 1 in an input field, but the model stores 1000.

Is there a way to transform a value before displaying/writing it?

EDIT:

In angular 1 there were `ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function() {...});` and `ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function() {...});`. Basically a way to add transformation in both ways.

Comment: Please share your code. It will help us to understand your problem.

Comment: There is no code yet, aside from an empty directive. It would like to bind a model value e.g. `myObject.x = 1000` to an input field, but the user should see a value of `1` in the input. If she/he enters `2` the underlying model should get updated to `2000`.

Comment: WHat if use enters 12? should it be 12000?

Comment: Yes. But that is only an example -e ven more transformation may be performed.

Comment: You can use directive with @Input.whats the problem?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Uf5BmI2r4RqufFB568x2?p=preview is this what you are lookin for?

Comment: The plnkr is not working... but i think  i see the approach. The problem is, i don't want tu just "autocorrect" the value. If a user enters 2, the input should keep showing 2. Only the model should get a transformed value.

Comment: A Value should "simply" be shown in another way than it gets stored.

Comment: Have you checked broswer's console?

Comment: Check now. I just removed one error.

Comment: Aah. Now it is working. How could i make it work in both directions? Lets say if the model is initially set to 1000 -> The user should see 1

Comment: THis way(two way) it is not possible. Or possible if you apply some good logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way:

```
<input [ngModel]="(x * 1000)" (change)="x = ($event.target.value / 1000)"
```

This way, a user sees a value of 1000 if the model value is 1. On change the model value will be updated accordingly.

Comment: I don't think `(change)=""` is correct. Use `(ngModelChange)="x = $event / 1000"` instead.

Answer (score -3):

I'd make a directive to achieve that,

**Working Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Uf5BmI2r4RqufFB568x2?p=preview**

```
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="model">
```

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer,Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[ngModel]' })

export class directive {
  @Input() ngModel;
  ngOnChanges(val:SimpleChanges){

    if(val['ngModel'].currentValue!=undefined)
    console.log(+val['ngModel'].currentValue*1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: `"Make a directive"`, `ngModel` is already a directive in angular

Comment: Not sure if it's even possible, but overwriting the existing directives not the right solution.